# Syncing Program Data Across Two Computers

Tags: c#, php, database, synchronization

I have a client requesting a **very** simple program that stores basic information that he were to input. The information would need to be shared across two computers on the same network, and the chances of the computers accessing the information concurrently from what I understand are slim to none.

I am not sure the practicality of setting up a full blown DBMS to handle minimal data across two computers. I was thinking perhaps a local (lite) db shared across the network to the two computers could handle this situation, which would be manipulated by a C# application. The database would require probably a maximum of 2-3 tables.

My other option would be a web based application (most likely PHP) running on a pre-configured server (perhaps WAMP or XAMPP), but I'm not sure how the network is configured where the program will be used, and I'm not sure if I can manage to keep the ports opened only in the local network, as I probably will not be able to touch any of the network settings.

The windows application or web application would most likely take me 2-3 days to write regardless of which option I choose, but I do not want to write one or the other and find that I chose the wrong option to suit the demands of the application.

Of the two options that I suggested, which would be the more practical solution? If there are any other options that would seem suitable for this situation, I am open to absolutely any suggestions. Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really simple? Excel (sharing a file, programable in VBA if you wanted to go a bit further) and Google Docs (which also have a forms engine) have this capability. No need to set anything up on any computer.

Comment: The program will be really simple to develop, but will not be fitting for a spread sheet. The program is a hauling manifest for heavy equipment.

Comment: Fair enough, you know the requirements. But you can consider Excel like a simple database, then the sheets act as tables and you manipulate through VBA. You do lose the power of SQL, though.

Comment: Due to the lack of answers, I'm going to accept your answer to my question. A follow up, I am going to be doing a web based application running off of my own server.